# Passing actions to child presentational component/accessing Route Params from child container component (ownProps)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4

So I have been building a shopping site and am at the point of cleaning up my code a bit.

I have a products page container component that rendered a:

1. category overview presentational component.
2. a list of brand filters and a list of price range filters (one individual filter being the presentational component).
3. a list of products (each product being one container component).

these all rendered with props that depended on the route within which the container component was rendered on.

Note that the products rendered would be modified with each filter selection using an action creator called by the filter that effects the products state in the redux store.

It all sounds like it should be clean but the filters lists where in a div that I could show/hide from view with a toggle. this was added last and was implemented in the container component as shown below:

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

import changeBrandFilter from '../actions/changeBrandFilter';
import changePriceFilter from '../actions/changePriceFilter';

import CategoryOverview from './CategoryOverview';
import Filter from './Filter';
import ProductsListItem from './ProductsListItem';
import ProductsPageContainerCSS from './ProductsPageContainer.css';
import Pagination from './Pagination';

class ProductsPage extends React.Component{
    createCategoryOverview() {
        let i = 1;
        return this.props.overview.map(overview => {
            i++
            return (
                <CategoryOverview 
                    key={"catOverview"+i} //each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop
                    title={overview.title}
                    text={overview.text}
                    image={overview.imageSource}
                    alt={overview.imageAlt}
                />
            )
        })
    }
    createBrandFilterList() {
        let i = 1;
        return this.props.brandFilters.map(filter => {
            i++
            return (
                <Filter
                    key={filter.brand+i+"brand"}
                    name={this.props.match.params.type + "brandFilter"} //so that each seperate group of radio buttons (filters) refer only to each other. (the name is shared within each group)
                    id={filter.brand}
                    changeFilterResetPageNumber={() => {this.props.changeBrandFilter(filter); this.handlePageChange(1)}} //without page reset would often get no products displayed on filter application due to the activePage state remaining at the page that was active at the time of filter application
                    inuse={filter.inuse}
                />
            )
        })
    }
    createPriceRangeFilterList() {
        let i = 1;
        return this.props.priceRangeFilters.map(filter => {
            i++
            return (
                <Filter
                    key={filter.priceRange+i+"priceRange"}
                    name={this.props.match.params.type + "priceFilter"} 
                    id={filter.priceRange}
                    changeFilterResetPageNumber={() => {this.props.changePriceFilter(filter); this.handlePageChange(1)}}
                    inuse={filter.inuse}
                />
            )
        })
    }
    filterDivExtenionToggle () {
            var filterDivExtension = document.querySelector('.filterDivExtension');
            var chevronUp = document.querySelector('#chevronUp');
            var chevronDown = document.querySelector('#chevronDown');
            if (filterDivExtension.style.display === 'block') {
                filterDivExtension.style.display = 'none';
                chevronUp.style.display = 'none';
                chevronDown.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                filterDivExtension.style.display = 'block';
                chevronUp.style.display = 'block';
                chevronDown.style.display = 'none';
            }
    }
    createProductsList() {
        if(this.props.products.length > 0) {
            return this.props.products.map(product =>{
                if (this.props.products.indexOf(product) >= (this.state.activePage*12) - 12 && this.props.products.indexOf(product) < (this.state.activePage*12)) { //render the 12 (number of products per page) products that correspond to the current (active) page
                    return (
                        <ProductsListItem
                            key={product.id}
                            brand={product.brand}
                            model={product.model}
                            price={product.price}
                            image={product.image}
                            link={"/"+this.props.match.params.type+"/"+product.id}
                        />
                    )
                }

            })} else {
                return <div>No products match the filter criteria selected above.</div>
            } 
    }
    state = {
        activePage: 1
    }
    handlePageChange(pageNumber) {
        this.setState({activePage: pageNumber});
    }
    createPagination() {
        if (this.props.products.length > 12) {
            if (this.props.products.length > this.state.activePage * 12 && this.state.activePage > 1) { //if there are products following AND preceding the current page
                return (
                    <Pagination 
                        onclick1={() => this.handlePageChange(this.state.activePage - 1)}
                        onclick2={() => this.handlePageChange(this.state.activePage + 1)}
                        disabled1={false}
                        disabled2={false}
                    />
                )
            } else if (this.props.products.length > this.state.activePage * 12) { //if there are only products following the current page
                return (
                    <Pagination 
                        onclick1={() => this.handlePageChange(this.state.activePage - 1)}
                        onclick2={() => this.handlePageChange(this.state.activePage + 1)}
                        disabled1={true}
                        disabled2={false}
                    />
                ) 
            } else if (this.state.activePage > 1) { //if there are only products preceding the current page
                return (
                    <Pagination 
                        onclick1={() => this.handlePageChange(this.state.activePage - 1)}
                        onclick2={() => this.handlePageChange(this.state.activePage + 1)}
                        disabled1={false}
                        disabled2={true}
                    />
                ) 
            }

        }
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="container">
                    {this.createCategoryOverview()}
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-12">
                            <div className= "filterDiv">
                                <div className="iconCrossbar">
                                    <i id="chevronDown" className="fa fa-chevron-down" onClick={this.filterDivExtenionToggle}></i>
                                    <i id="chevronUp" className="fa fa-chevron-up" onClick={this.filterDivExtenionToggle}></i>
                                </div>
                                <div className="filterDivExtension">
                                    <div className="row">
                                        <div className="filtersList col-md-5 col-11 mx-auto">
                                            Filter by Brand:
                                            <div>
                                                {this.createBrandFilterList()}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="filtersList col-md-5 col-11 mx-auto">
                                            Filter by Price Range:
                                            <div>
                                                {this.createPriceRangeFilterList()}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row productsList">
                        {this.createProductsList()}
                    </div>
                    {this.createPagination()}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
};

function mapStateToProps(state , ownProps) {
    let brandFilters = state.brandFilters;
    let filtered_brandFilters = brandFilters;
    filtered_brandFilters = filtered_brandFilters.filter(
        filter => filter.type === ownProps.match.params.type //gets type from the the route params and finds products which have type that matches
    )
    let priceRangeFilters = state.priceRangeFilters;
    let filtered_priceRangeFilters = priceRangeFilters;
    filtered_priceRangeFilters = filtered_priceRangeFilters.filter(
        filter => filter.type === ownProps.match.params.type
    )
    let overviews = state.overviews;
    let overview = overviews.filter(
        overview => overview.type === ownProps.match.params.type
    )
    let products = state.products;
    let filtered_products = products;
    filtered_products = filtered_products.filter(
        product => product.type === ownProps.match.params.type
    )
    let activeBrandFilters = filtered_brandFilters.filter(
        item => item.inuse === true
    );
    activeBrandFilters.forEach(filter => {
        if (filter.brand != "ALL") {
            filtered_products = filtered_products.filter(
                product => product.brand === filter.brand
            )
        }
    });
    let activePriceRangeFilters = filtered_priceRangeFilters.filter(
        item => item.inuse === true
    );
    activePriceRangeFilters.forEach(filter => {
        if (filter.priceRange != "ALL") {
            filtered_products = filtered_products.filter(
                product => product.priceRange === filter.priceRange
            );
        }
    });
    let key = ownProps.match.params.type;
    return {
        overview: overview,
        brandFilters: filtered_brandFilters,
        priceRangeFilters: filtered_priceRangeFilters,
        products: filtered_products,
        key: key //a change of key property means the component remounts. this was needed so that when on a second page of products (state is activePage: 2) and switching to a 'page' with products type that does not have a second page (uses same components but displays different type of products), no products would be displayed because the component did not remount and thh state remained the same (activePage did not reset to 1)
    };
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({changeBrandFilter: changeBrandFilter, changePriceFilter: changePriceFilter}, dispatch);
};

export const ProductsPageContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProductsPage);
```

As you can see the render looks messy so I went on to separate the whole filters list section into a child container component shown below:

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

import Filter from './Filter';

import changeBrandFilter from '../actions/changeBrandFilter';
import changePriceFilter from '../actions/changePriceFilter';

class FiltersLists extends React.Component {
    createBrandFilterList() {
        let i = 1;
        return this.props.brandFilters.map(filter => {
            i++
            return (
                <Filter
                    key={filter.brand+i+"brand"}
                    name={this.props.type + "brandFilter"} //so that each seperate group of radio buttons (filters) refer only to each other. (the name is shared within each group)
                    id={filter.brand}
                    changeFilterResetPageNumber={() => {this.props.changeBrandFilter(filter); this.props.handlePageChange(1)}} //without page reset would often get no products displayed on filter application due to the activePage state remaining at the page that was active at the time of filter application
                    inuse={filter.inuse}
                /> 
            )
        })
    }
    createPriceRangeFilterList() {
        let i = 1;
        return this.props.priceRangeFilters.map(filter => {
            i++
            return (
                <Filter
                    key={filter.priceRange+i+"priceRange"}
                    name={this.props.type + "priceFilter"} 
                    id={filter.priceRange}
                    changeFilterResetPageNumber={() => {this.props.changePriceFilter(filter); this.props.handlePageChange(1)}}
                    inuse={filter.inuse}
                />
            )
        })
    }
    filterDivExtenionToggle () {
            var filterDivExtension = document.querySelector('.filterDivExtension');
            var chevronUp = document.querySelector('#chevronUp');
            var chevronDown = document.querySelector('#chevronDown');
            if (filterDivExtension.style.display === 'block') {
                filterDivExtension.style.display = 'none';
                chevronUp.style.display = 'none';
                chevronDown.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                filterDivExtension.style.display = 'block';
                chevronUp.style.display = 'block';
                chevronDown.style.display = 'none';
            }
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <div className="col-12">
                <div className= "filterDiv">
                    <div className="iconCrossbar">
                        <i id="chevronDown" className="fa fa-chevron-down" onClick={this.filterDivExtenionToggle}></i>
                        <i id="chevronUp" className="fa fa-chevron-up" onClick={this.filterDivExtenionToggle}></i>
                    </div>
                    <div className="filterDivExtension">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="filtersList col-md-5 col-11 mx-auto">
                                Filter by Brand:
                                <div>
                                    {this.createBrandFilterList()}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="filtersList col-md-5 col-11 mx-auto">
                                Filter by Price Range:
                                <div>
                                    {this.createPriceRangeFilterList()}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state , ownProps) {
    let brandFilters = state.brandFilters;
    let filtered_brandFilters = brandFilters;
    filtered_brandFilters = filtered_brandFilters.filter(
        filter => filter.type === ownProps.match.params.type //gets type from the the route params and finds products which have type that matches
    )
    let priceRangeFilters = state.priceRangeFilters;
    let filtered_priceRangeFilters = priceRangeFilters;
    filtered_priceRangeFilters = filtered_priceRangeFilters.filter(
        filter => filter.type === ownProps.match.params.type
    )
    return {
        brandFilters: filtered_brandFilters,
        priceRangeFilters: filtered_priceRangeFilters,
//a change of key property means the component remounts. this was needed so that when on a second page of products (state is activePage: 2) and switching to a 'page' with products type that does not have a second page (uses same components but displays different type of products), no products would be displayed because the component did not remount and thh state remained the same (activePage did not reset to 1)
    };
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({changeBrandFilter: changeBrandFilter, changePriceFilter: changePriceFilter}, dispatch);
};

export const FiltersListsContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FiltersLists);
```

and now the parent container component looks like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

import changeBrandFilter from '../actions/changeBrandFilter';
import changePriceFilter from '../actions/changePriceFilter';

import CategoryOverview from './CategoryOverview';
import Filter from './Filter';
import {FiltersListsContainer} from './FiltersLists';
import ProductsListItem from './ProductsListItem';
import ProductsPageContainerCSS from './ProductsPageContainer.css';
import Pagination from './Pagination';

class ProductsPage extends React.Component{
    createCategoryOverview() {
        let i = 1;
        return this.props.overview.map(overview => {
            i++
            return (
                <CategoryOverview 
                    key={"catOverview"+i} //each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop
                    title={overview.title}
                    text={overview.text}
                    image={overview.imageSource}
                    alt={overview.imageAlt}
                />
            )
        })
    }
    createFiltersLists() {
        return (
            <FiltersListsContainer />
        )
    }
    createProductsList() {
        if(this.props.products.length > 0) {
            return this.props.products.map(product =>{
                if (this.props.products.indexOf(product) >= (this.state.activePage*12) - 12 && this.props.products.indexOf(product) < (this.state.activePage*12)) { //render the 12 (number of products per page) products that correspond to the current (active) page
                    return (
                        <ProductsListItem
                            key={product.id}
                            brand={product.brand}
                            model={product.model}
                            price={product.price}
                            image={product.image}
                            link={"/"+this.props.match.params.type+"/"+product.id}
                        />
                    )
                }

            })} else {
                return <div>No products match the filter criteria selected above.</div>
            } 
    }
    state = {
        activePage: 1
    }
    handlePageChange(pageNumber) {
        this.setState({activePage: pageNumber});
    }
    createPagination() {
        if (this.props.products.length > 12) {
            if (this.props.products.length > this.state.activePage * 12 && this.state.activePage > 1) { //if there are products following AND preceding the current page
                return (
                    <Pagination 
                        onclick1={() => this.handlePageChange(this.state.activePage - 1)}
                        onclick2={() => this.handlePageChange(this.state.activePage + 1)}
                        disabled1={false}
                        disabled2={false}
                    />
                )
            } else if (this.props.products.length > this.state.activePage * 12) { //if there are only products following the current page
                return (
                    <Pagination 
                        onclick1={() => this.handlePageChange(this.state.activePage - 1)}
                        onclick2={() => this.handlePageChange(this.state.activePage + 1)}
                        disabled1={true}
                        disabled2={false}
                    />
                ) 
            } else if (this.state.activePage > 1) { //if there are only products preceding the current page
                return (
                    <Pagination 
                        onclick1={() => this.handlePageChange(this.state.activePage - 1)}
                        onclick2={() => this.handlePageChange(this.state.activePage + 1)}
                        disabled1={false}
                        disabled2={true}
                    />
                ) 
            }

        }
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="container">
                    {this.createCategoryOverview()}
                    <div className="row">
                        {this.createFiltersLists()}
                    </div>
                    <div className="row productsList">
                        {this.createProductsList()}
                    </div>
                    {this.createPagination()}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
};

function mapStateToProps(state , ownProps) {
    let brandFilters = state.brandFilters;
    let filtered_brandFilters = brandFilters;
    filtered_brandFilters = filtered_brandFilters.filter(
        filter => filter.type === ownProps.match.params.type //gets type from the the route params and finds products which have type that matches
    )
    let priceRangeFilters = state.priceRangeFilters;
    let filtered_priceRangeFilters = priceRangeFilters;
    filtered_priceRangeFilters = filtered_priceRangeFilters.filter(
        filter => filter.type === ownProps.match.params.type
    )
    let overviews = state.overviews;
    let overview = overviews.filter(
        overview => overview.type === ownProps.match.params.type
    )
    let products = state.products;
    let filtered_products = products;
    filtered_products = filtered_products.filter(
        product => product.type === ownProps.match.params.type
    )
    let activeBrandFilters = filtered_brandFilters.filter(
        item => item.inuse === true
    );
    activeBrandFilters.forEach(filter => {
        if (filter.brand != "ALL") {
            filtered_products = filtered_products.filter(
                product => product.brand === filter.brand
            )
        }
    });
    let activePriceRangeFilters = filtered_priceRangeFilters.filter(
        item => item.inuse === true
    );
    activePriceRangeFilters.forEach(filter => {
        if (filter.priceRange != "ALL") {
            filtered_products = filtered_products.filter(
                product => product.priceRange === filter.priceRange
            );
        }
    });
    let key = ownProps.match.params.type;
    return {
        overview: overview,
        brandFilters: filtered_brandFilters,
        priceRangeFilters: filtered_priceRangeFilters,
        products: filtered_products,
        key: key //a change of key property means the component remounts. this was needed so that when on a second page of products (state is activePage: 2) and switching to a 'page' with products type that does not have a second page (uses same components but displays different type of products), no products would be displayed because the component did not remount and thh state remained the same (activePage did not reset to 1)
    };
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({changeBrandFilter: changeBrandFilter, changePriceFilter: changePriceFilter}, dispatch);
};

export const ProductsPageContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProductsPage);
```

now when i try and render the whole thing it throws an error saying TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined. this in relation to the child container component. It seems i cannot read the route params from the child container even though it is rendered through its parent component which is rendered on the route.

Is there any way to do this??

also to note is i tried to make the child container component as a presentational component that was passed in the presentation related props and the action related props. this actaully rendered and appeared just as it should but when i clicked on a filter the action creator was not calling with the right argument and it would throw an error along the lines of cannot read property 'brand' of undefined. clearly the action was not clearly stating what it was called upon.

So is there a propper way to pass down actions from container to presentational child and then to next presentational child (the individual filter)??

PS. I'm really sorry for the extremely long winded question but any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok sorry to anyone who may be annoyed over this one but I now have a solution.

So I went back to the first way i tried to do this which was just to seperate the FiltersLists into a child component that was not itself a container, and simply pass the props and action creators down, and then in turn pass the action creators down from that component down to the individual filters.

My struggle, as I now fully realise (I think), was getting the action creator to call on the right element.

originally I had something like this in the container component (ProductsPageContainer):

```
        brandFilterClick={() => this.props.changeBrandFilter()} 
        priceFilterClick={() => this.props.changePriceFilter()}
```

followed by this in its direct child component (FiltersLists):

```
createBrandFilterList() {
    let i = 1;
    return this.props.brandFilters.map(filter => {
        i++
        return (
            <Filter
                key={filter.brand+i+"brand"}
                name={this.props.type + "brandFilter"} //so that each seperate group of radio buttons (filters) refer only to each other. (the name is shared within each group)
                id={filter.brand}
                onFilterClick={() => {this.props.brandFilterClick(filter)}} //action creator passed from parent container component
                inuse={filter.inuse}
            />
        )
    })
}
createPriceRangeFilterList() {
    let i = 1;
    return this.props.priceRangeFilters.map(filter => {
        i++
        return (
            <Filter
                key={filter.priceRange+i+"priceRange"}
                name={this.props.type + "priceFilter"} 
                id={filter.priceRange}
                onFilterClick={() => {this.props.priceFilterClick(filter)}}
                inuse={filter.inuse}
            />
        )
    })
}
```

and then this in the lowest child component in the tree (Filter):

```
            <input type="radio"
                defaultChecked={this.props.inuse}
                name={this.props.name}
                onClick={() => this.props.onFilterClick()} //action creator passed down from container component
                />
            {'\u00A0'}{'\u00A0'}
            <label ref="text">{this.props.id}</label>
```

the issue was at this parent container component, all I had to do was change it to:

```
brandFilterClick={this.props.changeBrandFilter} //action creator passed down. this will not be called on the component that this function creates, but on the element in the component that is rendered by the component that this function creates - (ProductsPageContainer > FiltersLists > Filter - **input**). this is why no curley brackets. '()' were used here but in the component below - follow this action down the tree for more clarity.
priceFilterClick={this.props.changePriceFilter}
```

as I have stated in the comment on my code. I beleive this to be because the action creator is not being called as a function on the component that is rendered directly, but on the component that is then rendered by that component.

Although I managed to get there myself in the end I hope it may still be of use to anybody else with a similar issue.